# Sync Elastic Search data to Neo4j

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, logstash

I'm using elastic search as a main database now. Currently, i do need using neo4j to do some data mining stuff.

So, i need to sync elastic search data to neo4j. Is there any way to do that ? Or as least just get elastic search data and import to neo4j.

I recommended to use logstash. But i tried many way but can't do anything.

As i tried to use logstash to get data from elastic search. I can't get document's id. So that i can't create node from neo4j (I'll probably duplicate, i think). This is my code

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["myHost"]
    index => "myIndex"
    user => "xxx"
    password => "xxx"
    query => '{"query" : { "match_all" : {} }}'
    size => 10000
  }
}

output {
 file {
  path => "/home/tadada/Desktop/TEST/data.txt"
 }
}
```

So what should i use to do those thing ?

Thank you very much

Comment: you can import data from elastic to neo4j with the help of apoc library. https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_interacting_with_elastic_search